# How is floor division not giving result according to the documented rule?

Tags: python, floating-point, operators, division, floor-division

```
>>> print (12//0.2)
59.0
>>> print(floor(12/0.2))
60
```

Why floor division is not working according to the rule in this case?

p.s. Here Python is treating `0.2` as `0.20000000001` in the `floor division` case
So
`(12/0.2000000001)` is resulting in `59.999999...`
And `floor(59.999999999)` outputting `59`
But don't know why python is treating `0.2` as `0.2000000001`in the `floor division` case but not in the `division` case?

Comment: That's weird. Do you know why `12//0.2` gives 59.0?

Comment: Here Python is treating `0.2` as `0.2000000000000001`
So
`(12/0.2000000000000001)` is resulting in `59.999999...`

Comment: I am not a Python expert so i can't awnser this question, but you may find more revelant information here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: I would assume that the magic happens in the print and it rounds the 59.999999.... to 60. By the way is floor now printing 59 or 60? "And floor(59.999999999) outputting 59" but in the core it prints 60

Comment: @Klamsi That’s not what happens.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sure? http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

Comment: @Klamsi Sure. `print(12 / 0.2 == 60)`. Even OP’s code already ensures this isn’t what’s happening because they’re printing the result of `floor`, not of the division itself.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with print floor = 60. For me this makes no sense. But in the text he says: "And floor(59.999999999) outputting 59"

Comment: @Klamsi OP missed a few 9’s in there: `59.999999999999999` is `60`. These numbers have the **same** representation Python. Not similar, *identical* (`59.999999999999999 is 60.0` yields `True`). `12 / 0.2` really is equal to `60`, it’s not being rounded. This is all as expected. The real question is why `60 // 0.2` doesn’t have the same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why `12 / 0.2` results in 60.0, is not because 0.2 is treated differently, but because the error in the floating point division cancels the error in the representation of 0.2. The float always has the same value (greater than decimal 0.2), but depending on the operations those errors will either accumulate or be cancelled.

In other cases the error is not completely cancelled and shows up in the result:

```
>>> (12 / (0.2 * 0.2)) * 0.2
59.99999999999999
```

In CPython integer division for these specific types (float // float after the first param is automatically converted) and relative magnitudes is performed as follows (see [Python's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/86a93fddf72a2711aca99afa0c5374c8d6b4a321/Objects/floatobject.c#L616) for the full method):

```
mod = a % b
result = (a - mod) / b
```

If b was actually 0.2, then `mod` would be 0, but in floating point it is slightly larger, so `mod` is just under 0.2.

If you do this manually you can see how we end up with 59.0:

```
>>> a = 12.0
>>> b = 0.2
>>> mod = a % b
>>> mod
0.19999999999999934
>>> (a - mod) / b
59.0
```

The OP is also asking about the error in the floating point division, here's that as well:

The values (mantissa * base^exponent):

```
12:         1.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 * 2^3
0.2:        1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 * 2^(-3)
```

Remember 0.2 is not really 0.2, it's 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125. The result of dividing 12 by a value that is > 0.2 *should* be < 60.

To divide the values, we divide the mantissa and subtract the exponent, so we get:

```
12 / 0.2:   0.1110111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 * 2^6
```

But the last 3 bits don't fit into a double, which only has 53 bits for the mantissa (including the sign) and we're currently using 56.

Since the result starts with 0, we first normalise, multiplying the mantissa by 2 and subtracting one from the exponent. And then we have to round to the nearest 53 bit mantissa:

```
normalised: 1.110111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 * 2^5
rounded:    1.1110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 * 2^5
```

1.1110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 * 2^5 is equal to 60.

The difference between the correct result (1.110111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 * 2^5) and the closest value we can represent as a 64 bit double (1.1110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 * 2^5) is the error in the floating point division.

Comment: Thanks for the detailing info but what is the error in `floating point division` which cancels the `floating point` error.

Comment: I've added the details about the floating point division error.